# How to go back previous page in wicket framework

Tags: wicket

I have created a WebPage `A` which is called from many different pages. And there is a `back` button on Page `A`. So the `back` button should go to that previous page from where page `A` is called at that time.

I have already tried PageReference but it is not a successful idea for my problem because PageReferencing needs an `int` value and if I pass the previous page's reference via page parameter to Page `A` then it is not sure that last character will be an int value in previous page's reference which can be parsed into integer from string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plain JavaScript for this:

```
history.back();
```

or

```
history.go(-1);
```

i.e. `<a href="#" onclick="history.back()">Go back</a>`. Nothing Wicket specific.

Comment: Don't thank me. Please accept the answer so others benefit too.

Comment: You need to click a button/link next to the answer in StackOverflow to mark it as accepted. This way StackOverflow gives better score to the answer and it appears higher in the results when someone else asks similar question. Look around at the clickable elements around the top part of the answer.

Comment: I am new to the stack overflow so it doesn't show my vote publically but I have accepted the answer thus commented also.

Comment: It should show a green tick image below the number of upvotes and downvotes on the answer when it is properly accepted. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Great! Now you know how to work with StackOverflow,com! :-) Have fun!